# Android & iOS scan network for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android, ios, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I want my Android and iOS (Swift to be specific) apps to connect to the Raspberry Pi in the network. Of course I can set a fix IP for the Pi and hardcode the IP to the apps, but I would like to know how to do it more dynamically.

What do I need to do on both sides to allow the apps to discover the Pi?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected over Wifi(Access Point) then you can discover devices using **SSDP** protocol.which does multicast at **1900** port and whoever has joined to particular group will receive and can respond back with information.It can be implemented both side App as well as Pi.