# Finding a RaspberryPi's local IP address from iOS

Tags: ios, raspberry-pi, ip-address

I'm using CocoaMQTT to connect to a mosquitto server running on a Raspberry Pi so that I can control a Pi-based robot over Wi-Fi. It works great, but I'm currently coding the bot's IP address into the iOS app's Swift code with this call:

```
let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "iOS Device", host: "10.0.1.9", port: 1883)
```

I'd like to be able to find the Pi/bot if I put it on any open WiFi network (or my School address, where the Mac address is registered & allowed). This would make the code more generic so the user wouldn't have to know an IP address before connecting to the bot.

I've tried replacing the IP address in the String above with a String of the Pi's name (e.g. "pibot", "pibot.local", but none seem to work.

Can I find a device's IP address from Swift code, or formatting the Pi's name differently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36821825/341994